# Create a new Table with pgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to create a new table with plpgsql, but I want that the user gives the name of the table.My code generate a table with the name of **tbname**

this is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Object_gen"(tablename text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$DECLARE
tbname text;
BEGIN
tbname:=tablename;
CREATE TABLE tbname(Surrogat uuid);
END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can I solve my problem? somehow that the name of my table comes from the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Object_gen"(tablename text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  execute 'CREATE TABLE '||tablename||' (Surrogat uuid)';
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```